Photon Quantum Error: Multiple Assembly Definition Files
So basically I imported Photon Quantum, everything went well! Except after I played for the first time, It showed up with a error saying, "Folder 'Assets/Photon/PhotonRealtime/Code/' contains multiple assembly definition files (Assets/Photon/PhotonRealtime/Code/PhotonRealtime.asmdef)" and there is two of them. Both are the same.
enter image description here
I don't know what to do, It is my first time experimenting with Quantum. I only know how to use Photon PUN and this is starting to confuse me.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
